# Meaning of "I got my"

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between and when to use them?
1. I got my hair stuck in the nail
2. My hair got stuck in the nail

I Know about this
1. I got my hair cut - Means - Having some one else do the hair cut
2. I cut my hair - Means - doing the hair cut by the same person

Comment: The sequence *[subject] got [object] [past tense verb]* usually implies ***...by someone else***. But not always - a statement such as *I [finally] got my homework finished [last night]* wouldn't normally be understood as meaning I had someone else finish it for me (but in a contrived context, it might mean that).

Comment: Neither option is natural. “In a nail” would mean _inside_ the nail, which doesn’t make any sense. Getting something _stuck_ in/on/to something implies either that 1) the something is capable of exerting pressure from more than one side at a time (finger stuck in a door, hand stuck in a jar, shoe stuck in snow/mud/sand); or 2) the something is highly sticky or adhesive (pancake stuck on the ceiling, picture stuck to the wall). Hair on a nail is neither—you don’t get your hair stuck on a nail. You be more likely to say your hair **catches** (or **gets caught**) on a nail.

Comment: Also look up information on "passive" in English.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your two examples:

> 1. I got my hair stuck in the nail.
> 2. My hair got stuck in the nail.

The *former* specifies that *you* are responsible, by usage of the pronoun *"I"* as the subject (actor) of the sentence.

The *latter* leaves *open* as to who is responsible; it could be you, or another person, or the outcome of circumstances (maybe the wind blew your hair).

Regarding this usage of "got" (past tense of "get"):

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get):

> 3.1 [*as auxiliary verb*] Used with past participle to form the passive mood.
>   *‘the cat got drowned’*

[American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=G5113800):

> *v. intr.* 3. b. Used with the past participle of transitive verbs as a passive voice auxiliary: *got stung by a bee.*